# Curvature and spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spacetime, tensor-calculus, curvature

Suppose that it is given that the Riemann curvature tensor in a special kind of spacetime of dimension $d\geq2$ can be written as   $$R_{abcd}=k(x^a)(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$$ where $x^a$ is a vector in the space.

What condition can I impose on $d$ to guarantee that $k(x^a)$ is a constant? I have been told that such a condition exists.

Not knowing what to do, I computed the contractions of the curvature tensor and got 
$$R_{bd}=g^{ac}R_{abcd}=k(d-1)g_{bd}$$ and 
$$R=g^{bd}g^{ac}R_{abcd}=kd(d-1)$$
But it probably is of no use?

Comment: I don't know if this works, but maybe you want to use the fact that the Einstein tensor is covariantly conserved.